# Set opacity for parent form when executing ShowDialog method

Tags: c#, winforms

I  have 5 forms (c# winforms) and my application uses only one form as Parent and all the child forms are shown by calling ShowDialog method on demand. I wish to have the child form to be focused and I am setting Opacity = 0.83 before calling ShowDialog method for any child form and then I reset it to 1. But I need to do this on all the places. Is there any common way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Encapsulate` the logic in `single method` and always use that method for calling your child forms something like -

```
public void ShowChildForm()
{
   this.Opacity = 0.83;
   // show dialog logic here
   this.Opacity = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is useful, because ShowDialog logic for 5 different form must be different, so it's not encapsulated in one method already

Comment: I could write the method as,

public DialogResult ShowChildForm(Form childForm)
{
   this.Opacity = 0.83;
   DialogResult dr = childForm.ShowDialog();
   this.Opacity = 1.0;
   return dr;
}

Comment: @VahiD - How `ShowDialog` can be different? Its just `form.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Albert corrected your answer in comment. ShowDialog of which form must be called?

Comment: I guess that was `implicit` that's why i leave out the `showDialog` logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I was looking for,

```
 public DialogResult ShowChildForm(Form childForm)
{
      this.Opacity = 0.83;
      DialogResult dr = childForm.ShowDialog();
      this.Opacity = 1.0;
      return dr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to ChildForm's Load and Closed events in Parent form, like this :

```
    public partial class Parent : Form
{
    public Parent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new ChildForm();
        form.Load += form_Load;
        form.Closed += form_Closed;
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    void form_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity = 1;
    }

    void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity = 0.85;
    }


}
```

Comment: every child form you are creating must subscribe to this events, so they control the opacity of parent form

Comment: what happens, If I call form.Show(). I do not want to have opacity for parent form, when calling show method.